# Can't delete Backbone.View causing zombies

Tags: backbone.js, memory-management, coffeescript, view

I can't seem to completely destroy my Backbone.Views. I have tried all the suggestions and still they turn into zombies and start an apocalypse on my memory. Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

When I toggle back and forth between routes /access and /settings the browser creates new instances as expected, the close method fires and completes, however the profiler in chrome says something the previous instances are hanging around.

[image: ZombieApocalypse]

### My BaseView

```coffeescript
class BaseView extends Backbone.View

  # -------------------------------------------

  isRendered: false
  autoDestroy: false

  # -------------------------------------------

  close: ->
    log 'Closing View', @, @model

    @onClose() if @onClose?

    @remove() if @?
    @unbind() if @? # Unbind all local event bindings


    delete @$el # Delete the jQuery wrapped object variable
    delete @el # Delete the variable reference to this node
    delete @

    log 'Everything is destroyed', @

  # -------------------------------------------

module.exports = BaseView
```

### My Router

```coffeescript
class Router extends BaseRouter

  name: "Router"
  container: "#content-container"
  routes: routes

  #----------------------

  access: (slug) ->

    AccessPage = require '../view/page/access-page.coffee'
    accessPage = new AccessPage()
    accessPage.render()
    @showPage accessPage


  #----------------------

  settings: (slug) ->

    SettingsPage = require '../view/page/settings-page.coffee'
    settingsPage = new SettingsPage()
    settingsPage.render()
    @showPage settingsPage
```

### My BaseRouter

```coffeescript
class BaseRouter extends Backbone.Router

  currentPageView: null
  pageClass: '.page'

  # -------------------------------------------

  showPage: (view, hidePages = true) ->

    @hideAllPages() if hidePages

    @currentPageView = view

    $(@container).append view.$el

    log 'showPage', view.$el

    view.$el.show()

  # -------------------------------------------

  hideAllPages: ->

    if @currentPageView?.onHide?
      @currentPageView.onHide()

    if @currentPageView? and @currentPageView.autoDestroy
      @currentPageView.close()

    $(@pageClass).hide()
```

### One of my Views

```coffeescript
class AccessPage extends BaseView

  name: "AccessPage"
  id: "access-page"
  autoDestroy: true
  className: 'page'

  #----------------------

  initialize: ->
    log @name, "initialize"

  #----------------------

  render: ->
    log @name, "render"

    @$el.html template
      title: "Access"

    @isRendered = true

  #----------------------


module.exports = AccessPage
```

Comment: Do you mind using MarionetteJS with Backbone? Its really helpfull

Comment: I would really love to avoid it, if possible. I am reluctant to go with the pattern of having separate baseViews for Page and Subview which I believe is the marionette structure. I will eventually have subviews in subviews and what I was hoping to great was a singular baseview which when destroyed, recursively destroys any subviews it has. That being said, if I can't get these views destroyed on my own I will definitey be open to it because I need a solution.

Comment: if i got you point correct your eventual plans is very close to Marionette idea. It has Few types of views, extended from upgraded Backbone view. Any type of view recursively close its child views. Also, about separate baseViews in marionette, Marionette has View, as base for all other types of views, but there is no relation where to use it, as page view or sub view. All view types may be used nearly everywhere.

Comment: Fair enough. I would still love to work out why this isn't working, though. Any ideas?

Comment: For the hell of it I swapped out the my baseview for a Marrionette.View. And that did work. So there is hope. However, Marionette comes with so much stuff I don't need, and I noticed this note in the docs _Note: The Marionette.View class is not intended to be used directly. It exists as a base view for other view classes to be extended from, and to provide a common location for behaviors that are shared across all views._ Which suggests that I adopt their collection.view / item.view paradigm. So I am still open to a non marionette solution.

Comment: last post as Marionette evangelist :) not Backbone nor Marionette force you to follow collectionViem / ItemView , its just a way to render collections.Anyway you can checkout marionette view work flow and borrow some useful stuff, especially after code clean up in v 2.0.x

Comment: True, I guess you are right, as long as I extend Marionette.View then it does what I want. Still completely stumped though. And I can't give up until I know what I am doing wrong. arrrgggghhhh!!!

Comment: I just tried your suggestion and removed the log functions completely. Still no luck. I have also replaced the contents of my close method with the marionette destroy method and vice versa. Marionette always works and mine does not. I must have seriouls f'ed something up.